# IP addressing - Network prefix - Help understanding

Tags: networking, ip, prefix

I am currently studying for an IT exam, and looking into IP addressing. I have thus come across the following question:

**For a given class C network 194.1.2.3, what is the network prefix?**

I know this is a fairly simple, theoretical question, but I need to understand why. So far, I have the following working:

IPv4 applies dotted-decimal notation to divide the 32-bit address into four 8-bit fields (for readability).

Furthermore, the IP address space (not sure if right term) is divided into three classes (A, B, and C) to support networks of different sizes (classful addressing).

```
XXXX . XXXX . XXXX. XXXX
```

I also know the following:

```
Address Class A    A(/8 prefixes)
Address Class B    B(/16 prefixes)
Address Class C    C(/24 prefixes)
```

I have thus concluded that **194.1.2** constitutes the network prefix of the given class C network, seeing that these make up the first 24 bytes.

Is this correct; and if so: Would the prefix for class A and class B networks be 194 and 194.2 respectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classful networking was deprecated over 20 years ago, and I don't understand why it is still taught since nothing uses it anymore.

The network class has noting to do with the network mask, but the classes have default masks.

- Class A network addresses start with the first bit as `0`, giving you
  `0.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255` as the Class A address range. The
  default mask for Class A networks is `255.0.0.0`.
- Class B network addresses start with the first two bits as `10`,
  giving you `128.0.0.0` to `191.255.255.255` as the Class B range. The
  default mask for Class B networks is `255.255.0.0`.
- Class C network addresses start with the first three bits as `110`,
  giving you `192.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255` as the Class C range. The
  default mask for Class C addresses is `255.255.255.0`.
- Class D addresses start with the first four bits as `1110`, giving
  you the `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255` as the Class D range. Class
  D addresses are used for multicast, and multicast doesn't normally
  use masks since multicast groups are subscribed to individually.
- Class E addresses start with the first four bits as `1111`, giving
  you the `240.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255` as the Class E range. Class
  E addresses are reserved/experimental so they don't have a default
  mask, except for the Limited Broadcast address of `255.255.255.255`
  which is a host address with the mask of `255.255.255.255`.